# How can i filter my data from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, filter

Let's say i have 3 tables:

```
table:     SONGS
cell:      ID            primary key
cell:      TITLE
cell:      ADD_TIME

table:     CATEGORIES
cell:      ID            primary key
cell:      title

table:     SONGS_CATEGORIES
cell:      ID            primary key
cell:      SONG_ID
cell:      CATEGORY_ID
```

Then let's assume that I have 3 songs(with id's 0, 1, 2), and I have 5 categories(rock, pop, rap and so on) and respectively, their id's(0, 1, 2...). How my sql query should look like, if I want to be able to select more than one category, then I need to look into table SONGS_CATEGORIES and get all songs_id with category id I selected, and then i get songs from table SONGS with those id's?

Hope i explained what i need pretty well, English is not my native language.

Comment: Use join syntax, perhaps an `in` statement for "if I want to be able to select more than one category"   This may help you understand joins: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: I tried one `JOIN` and got stuck because i just can't imagine in my head how this should look like.

Comment: You should have a read of this [Question and Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12475850/1450077) I posted a while back. It is a really long tutorial just for instances like this.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a bunch of work, I will definitely read that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know the ID numbers of the categories that you're wanting songs from then the following should do the trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM SONGS s
     JOIN SONGS_CATEGORIES sc
       ON s.ID = sc.SONG_ID
WHERE sc.CATEGORY_ID IN (@id1, @id2, @id3...@idN);
```

If you only know the names of the categories you want the songs for then you can use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM SONGS s
     JOIN SONGS_CATEGORIES sc
       ON s.ID = sc.SONG_ID
     JOIN CATEGORIES c
       ON sc.CATEGORY_ID = c.ID
WHERE c.title IN (@catTitle1, @catTitle2, @catTitle3...@catTitleN);
```

In both of these examples you would replace the @ with the data you are providing and adjust the SELECT part to show only the columns you need.

Comment: This is working well for me, and it looks pretty clean, but i still get the same result more than 1 time.

Comment: Is this idea looking fine, with that GROUP BY? `SELECT * FROM songs s JOIN s_in_tag sc ON s.id = sc.song_id WHERE sc.tag_id IN (2, 3) GROUP BY(s.id)`

Comment: Grouping by the SONGS.ID will clean things up should you have a song related to more than one of the categories that you have in your where clause.

Comment: Yes, i should have a song related to more than one of the categories.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select songs from categories 1 & 2 :

```
SELECT s.id song_id, s.title song_title, s.add_time song_add_time, c.id cat_id, c.title cat_title
FROM CATEGORIES c
INNER JOIN SONGS_CATEGORIES sg
ON c.id = sg.category_id
INNER JOIN SONGS s
ON sg.song_id = s.id
WHERE c.id = 1 OR c.id = 2
```

Comment: So `OR` expression is enough? But what if same song is present in 2 or more categories, won't then sql show me twice that song?

Comment: Try DISTINCT(s.id).. not sure it works but try anyway

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you need

```
SELECT * -- select what ever columns you need to display
FROM   SONGS s
       JOIN SONGS_CATEGORIES sc
         ON s.ID = sc.SONG_ID
       JOIN CATEGORIES c
         ON c.ID = sc.CATEGORY_ID 
 where c.title in ('title1','title2')
```

Comment: @RaduDascălu what are the columns you are selecting. whether the entire row is repeated